# Implementing simple relationships between models

Tags: php

I have two tables `orders` and `addresses`:

```
   ORDERS                      ADDRESSES
------------                 ------------
id                           id
customer_id                  street
address_id     --- n:1 ---   city
status                       state
total                        country
created_at                   zip
```

An `order` has one address, and an `address` can belong to many `orders`. I also have two models, `Order` and `Address` to represent the entities.

### Problem

Suppose that a view needs to display order history in an HTML table, which must contain information from **both** `orders` and `addresses` tables (status, total, shipping address, etc.).

One way to do this is to fetch data into two independent objects, `Order` and `Address`, using either two `SELECT` queries with `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` or a single `INNER JOIN` query on two tables with `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` (and then manually map them into objects). However, in both cases the two objects would have no connection. It would be much more convenient if `Address` could be loaded together with `Address`, something like this:

```
$order = Order::all()->with('Address')
```

**How can I implement this simple relationship using plain PHP?**

My `all()` method so far:

```
public static function all() {
    return DB::run('SELECT * FROM users')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'User');
}
```

and the `DB` class is a simple wrapper borrowed from [phpdelusions.net](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper#code)

BONUS: Since I have a `DB` class, should I put methods such as `with`, `all`, `find`, `where`, etc. in the parent `Model` class or in an `ORM` class to be on top of `DB`?

Comment: If you want to use an ORM, why not just choose one that already have those features, like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects.html) or similar? It feels a bit like reinventing a very common wheel, otherwise.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson It's done for learning purposes only, but thanks for the suggestion anyways. I would still like to learn the basic principles though. Sometimes the complexity of a full-fledged ORM can be overwhelming